# JMeter JMS Publisher taking incorrect data from CSV config

Tags: jmeter, jms, mq

When i did the paramerization for the JMS publisher using CSV config file, some how 1st row taking unknown characters.I have double checked the csv file ,it didn't notice extra spaces before the data.

Not able to figured out what went wrong.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These characters are the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Ensure you set in [CSV DataSet](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)  **File encoding** to UTF-8.

[image: CSV Data Set encoding]